# R can't find RSQLite package when run in Emacs (iESS)

Tags: windows-7, emacs, r

I have R 3.0.2 (both x64 and x86) running on Windows 7 x64. I've recently started using Emacs as a front-end to R (x64) via the [iESS](http://ess.r-project.org/) mode.

This normally works well, the only catch is that I have to run R in elevated mode to install packages (due to Windows 7 UAC). I've done so to install a few packages (ggplot2, RPostgreSQL, RODBC, RGDAL), all of which seem to work fine from within Emacs.

The exception to this is RSQLite. I've installed the package as normal, and I can load it with `library(RSQLite)` if I run a standalone instance of R. But, if I run R from within Emacs and try to run `library(RSQLite)` i get the following error message:

> Error in library(RSQLite) : there is no package called 'RSQLite'

The only other difference is that I have a workspace saved that is automatically loaded when I run R through Emacs. Is this workspace causing RSQLite not to be found? Has anyone else encountered this issue?